# NextAuth + Nextjs 13 - Unable to add user role

Tags: authentication, session, next.js, jwt, next-auth

**OVERVIEW OF THE APP**

I have implemented authentication in my Next.js web app using NextAuth. Note that I am using Google OAuth provider.

[image]

The authentication is working as expected.

**WHAT AM I TRYING TO DO?**

I am trying to **add role based access control** in my app. I want all the users (except 2 email addresses of mine) who sign in to be assigned a role called `user`. When I sign in using any of my 2 email addresses, I want to be assigned a role called `admin`.

Then, I want the `role` field to be accessible in both the client and server components of my Next.js app. Also, I want to use the user role to  do routing checks inside my `middleware.ts` file. (I want some routes to be only accessible to users with the role `admin`.)

**WHAT HAVE I TRIED?**

So, I read the official NextAuth documentation on role based access control available at the following link:

https://authjs.dev/guides/basics/role-based-access-control

Note that I am using **jwt-based session startegy**. Based on the official documentation, I added a function called `profile()` inside `GoogleProvider`. Inside this function, I have the logic that decides whom to apply which role. And then I return the object that I want to be available to the `user` parameter inside the `jwt` and `session` callbacks.

Here is my code inside the `auth.ts` file, where I have configured NextAuth:

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@auth/firebase-adapter";
import { cert } from "firebase-admin/app";
import type { Adapter } from "next-auth/adapters";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
      profile(profile) {
        let role;
        if (
          profile.email === "abc@gmail.com" ||
          profile.email === "xyz@gmail.com"
        ) {
          role = "admin";
        } else {
          role = "user";
        }

        const user = {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.name,
          email: profile.email,
          role,
        };

        console.log("User object inside the profile function:", user);

        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter({
    credential: cert({
      projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY!.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
    }),
  }) as Adapter,
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        console.log("User object inside the jwt callback:", user);
        token.role = user.role;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      // Add the user's role to the session
      if (session.user) {
        console.log("User object inside the session callback:", session.user);
        session.user.role = token.role;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};
```

Also, I have extended the default `user`, `jwt` and `session` types in a file called next-auth.d.ts:

```
import { DefaultSession, DefaultUser } from "next-auth";
import { JWT, DefaultJWT } from "next-auth/jwt";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface User extends DefaultUser {
    role: string;
  }

  interface Session extends DefaultSession {
    user: User;
  }
}

declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  interface JWT extends DefaultJWT {
    role: string;
  }
}
```

Have I extended the types correctly?

**WHAT DO I UNDERSTAND ABOUT ADDING USER ROLES?**

This is what I understand about adding user roles in NextAuth. (*Please correct me if I am wrong*)

1. The object you return from the `profile()` function becomes the `user` object for the other callbacks: `jwt` and `session`. In other words, when you return an object with a `role` property from `profile()`, this `role` is automatically part of `user` object in the later stages, especially  `jwt` and `session` callbacks.

As you can see below, I am returning an object from the `profile()` function that contains a property called `role`.

```
      profile(profile) {
        let role;
        if (
          profile.email === "rawgrittt@gmail.com" ||
          profile.email === "pgcim14.hemant@spjimr.org"
        ) {
          role = "admin";
        } else {
          role = "user";
        }

        const user = {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.name,
          email: profile.email,
          role,
        };

        console.log("User object inside the profile function:", user);

        return user;
      },
```

If I console.log the `user` object, I see that the role is being correctly assigned:

[image]

**WHAT PROBLEM AM I FACING?**

If my understanding of how role based access control works is correct, when I console.log the `user` object inside the `jwt` and `session` callbacks, I should see the `role` property. But I don't see them. As a result, I am not bale to access the `role` property inside any client or server component.

Here's the shape of the `user` object inside the `jwt` callback:

[image]

As you can see, it doesn't contain a `role` property:

Here's the shape of the `user` object inside the `session` callback:

[image]

As you can see, it doesn't contain a `role` property either:

**WHAT IS MY QUESTION?**

I have two questions:

1. Why the role property is not available inside `session` and `jwt` callbacks?
2. If the user object returned from the `profile()` function is the exact object available inside the `jwt` and `session` callbacks (assuming my understanding is correct), why do I have different signatures of the `user` object inside `jwt` and `session` callbacks? For example, `emailVerified` is not part of the `user` object returned from the `profile()` function, but it is present in the `user` object inside the `jwt` callback.

If you have implemented role based access control, I would appreciate your help in this. Thanks.